# Silverlight XAML listbox with a specific set of columns

Tags: silverlight, xaml, listbox

My goal is to have a selectable list with 3 items. For the selection I would want to use a Listbox and the 3 items should be spaced equally over the complete width of the screen.

My first try is to put a grid with columns in my listbox's itemstemplate, but all items are put in the first column by default.:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding list}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

How can I make it so that they are also put in the other two?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe a horizontal listbox is what you need? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688015/display-list-of-items-horizontally-in-silverlight-4

Comment: That would work, apart from the requirement that the three items need to have an equal width